# UIImageView.image update lag in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

Can anyone explain the following observed behavior on iOS (iOS7 specifically):

I have a custom UITableViewCell class. For simplicity, here are the relevant methods of the class, including layoutSubviews:

```
// CustomCell.h
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
   UITextView *textView;
   UIImageView *backgroundImage;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *textView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *backgroundImage;
@end

// CustomCell.m
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];
  if (self.message.isIncoming) 
  {
    self.textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"incomingImage.png"];  
  }
  else 
  {
    self.textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"outgoingImage.png"];  
  }
}
```

Here is how it is set:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Message *chatMessage = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setMessage:chatMessage];
    return cell;
}
```

The content and positioning of both the textView and backgroundImage are done elsewhere and done correctly 100% of the time.

Can anyone explain the scenario where I would see an incoming message with whiteText, but using the outgoingImage background? Then a second later, the background correctly updates to incomingImage, and the user sees the background change.

Basically I am seeing a cell re-used where the text is correct and the textColor is correct, but sometimes the backgroundImage is not correct. I wonder if there is some kind of delay in applying the .image property of a UIImageView? I know that layoutSubviews was called, because if it was not the textColor wouldn't be correct. It's just the image property of the UIImageView that will sometimes either be incorrect or not update right away.

Note that textView and backgroundImage are both custom views that I have added as subviews of the contentView of a custom UITableViewCell

Comment: Do your cells transition in or out of editing mode during this process?

Comment: They are not in editing mode during this process. They are in a beginUpdates/insertRowsAtIndexPaths/endUpdates or a reloadData.